# refactoring old php with reflection

Tags: php, reflection

so I am refactoring some old code written by someone else. I've come across this:

```
$r = new \ReflectionClass($className);
$args = (is_subclass_of($className, 'ClassA')) ? [$arg1, $arg2] : [$arg2];
$classInstance = $r->newInstanceArgs($args);
```

my question is, why would the person do this? Doesn't this do the same?

```
$args = (is_subclass_of($className, 'ClassA')) ? [$arg1, $arg2] : [$arg2];
$classInstance = new $className($args);
```

The code is a few years old - the reason could have something to do with old PHP version features. I'm just looking for reasons and confirmation that the second way is "better". Thanks.

Comment: Unless the person wrote this suddenly pops up and recognizes the code as his / hers, I doubt you'll ever get a chance of a answer, this we can't read the persons mind.

Comment: of course not, but we can _infer_ reasoning and also be sure code is correct for the situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the answer is because of the "dynamic argument list." So the second version would have to look like this to be **correct**:

```
if (is_subclass_of($className, 'ClassA')) {
    $classInstance = new $className($arg1, $arg2);
} else {
    $classInstance = new $className($arg2);
}
```

passing an `array` to either constructor doesn't work:

```
class ClassA
{
    public $arg1;
    public $arg2;

    public function __construct($arg1, $arg2)
    {
        $this->arg1 = $arg1;
        $this->arg2 = $arg2;
    }
}

$className = 'ClassA';

$args = (is_subclass_of($className, 'ClassA')) ? [1, 2] : [2];
$classInstance = new $className($args);

var_dump($classInstance);

// object(ClassA)[1]
//  public 'arg1' => 
//    array (size=1)
//      0 => int 2
//  public 'arg2' => null
```

Comment: wow! only one appointment: program with this technique will be a nightmare for sure! You lost traceability in your IDE.

Comment: that is true, but with reflection, it is no better.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for this purpose ReflectionClass is unnecessary.

You need to be sure that $r is not used in other part of the code before to remove it.

FYI:

- is_subclass_of is available since PHP 4
- ReflectionClass::isSubclassOf is available since PHP 5

You should check if instanceof match with your requirements, I think that it's a good solution

http://php.net/instanceof

```
($a instanceof MyClass)
```

Comment: thanks for the response. please see my answer below. what do you think of that?

Comment: `instanceof` requires an instantiated object, which is unavailable here.

Comment: oh, yes! sorry I understand you now, you have not an object yet, you are creating it.